# Criando Pontos no Google Maps com Dados do PHP

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

## O que preciso

Preciso que atráves do PHP eu receba localidades e possa marcá-las como pontos no Google Maps.

## O que eu fiz

Criei uma parte em Ajax pra chamar o script em PHP que faz a consulta e retorna o json. Ele recebe os dados. Ele está adicionando os pontos no mapa, porém quando eu clico em algum deles ele não abre a caixa com as informações.

## JS

```
var map;
var idInfoBoxAberto;
var infoBox = [];
var markers = [];
var localizacao = [];
//var markerPonto = new google.maps.Marker({});
var markerPonto;
var contador = 0;
var l = 0;
var contentString;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    maxWidth: 300
});

/*Método que inicia configurações iniciados do mapa*/
function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-23.5514565,-46.6224739);

    var options = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), options);

    /*Novo parte - adiciona ponteiro geolocalizador(de acordo com as coordenadas informadas em 'latlng'*/
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
    });

    marker.setPosition(latlng);

    /*Parte de loop com banco de dados*/
    $.ajax({
        url : 'verificaAjax.php',
        success : function(msg){
            if (msg.status == 0) {
                msg.errorMsg.forEach(ShowResults);
                //JSON.parse(msg.errorMsg).forEach(ShowResults);

            }
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("Erro no Processamento dos Dados. Entre em contato com o setor de Tecnologia e informe a mensagem abaixo:\n"+xhr.responseText);
        }

    });

}

// Função para retornar os valores
function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {
    contentString = '<h2>'+value['razao_social']+'</h2>';

    localizacao.push({
        nome: value['razao_social'],
        latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(value['latitude'],value['longitude'])
    });


    /*
    markerPonto.position(localizacao[l].latlng);
    markerPonto.icon('img/marcador.png');
    markerPonto.map(map);
    markerPonto.title(localizacao[l].nome);
    */


    markerPonto = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: localizacao[l].latlng,
        icon: 'img/marcador.png',
        map: map,
        title: localizacao[l].nome
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(markerPonto, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map,v);
    });

    ++l;


}
```

## PHP

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json;');
    require('bd.php');

    $bancoDeDados = new Bd();

    //Armazena o resultado
    $mensagemResultado = array("status" => 1, "errorMsg" => array());

    //Obtem todos os resultados de pontos de entrega
    $resultadoConsulta = $bancoDeDados->selectPontos();
    if (count($resultadoConsulta) > 0) {
        $mensagemResultado["status"] = 0;
        $mensagemResultado["errorMsg"] = array_merge($mensagemResultado["errorMsg"],$resultadoConsulta);
    }

    echo json_encode($mensagemResultado);
```

Comment: Acho que estás a esquecer de fazer _parse_ desses dados que vêm do PHP. Já testaste `JSON.parse(msg.errorMsg).forEach(ShowResults);` ? ou usar `type: 'json'` na configuração do AJAX?

Comment: Os pontos mudam de lugar com o tempo? Se forem fixos, nao precisa do Ajax, basta gerar o source do mapa pelo PHP mesmo.

Comment: @Sergio Tenho uma outra solução onde implementei o envio dos dados do formulário pelo json passando pra um php(assim como nesse código) e retornando pro JS. Peguei inclusive ele como base, e não precisei fazer nenhuma conversão dos dados.

Comment: @Bacco Sim. Eles poderão ser modificados futuramente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estou assumindo que:

- No mapa, só deve permanecer aberta uma caixa, o infowindow (quero dizer, clicando num outro marcador fecha o infowindow e re-abre no local novo)
- A razão social pode ser bem comprida

Fiz as seguintes alteraçoes para o mapa mostrar a caixa quando um marcador é clicado.

Tirei a definição inicial de `content` da caixa porque será substituida depois.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    // content: contentString,   
    maxWidth: 300
});
```

Adicionar a palavra-chave `var` antes do `markerPonto` (sem esse var, o markerPonto vira variavel global), e nós queremos um separado para cada `addListener`.

```
var markerPonto = new google.maps.Marker({
    ...
```

Finalmente, para cada Listener, é preciso criar um escopo novo para lembrar o valor da Razao Social. Para isso uso uma funçao anonima. (funçoes criam escopos novos em JavaScript). Sem usa-lo, apareceria o mesmo valor, o ultimo, em todas as caixas.

```
  (function(contentString) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markerPonto, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent('<div style="line-height: 1.35;">' + contentString + '</div>');
      infowindow.open(map, markerPonto);
    });
  })(contentString);
```

A adição do `line-height` é pra evitar um problema que encontrei enquanto testava. Sem ela, aparecia um scrollbar dentro da caixa.

Simulei a parte de puxar dados simplesmente chamando o `ShowResults` :

```
ShowResults({'razao_social': 'Carlos',
           'latitude': -23.44,
           'longitude': -43.22,
          });
```

Ver [**demonstração no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tc1k4sd5/)

Comment: Genial ! Você não sabe o quanto fica agradecido.

Comment: Uma coisa que gostaria de fazer, é o quando acumulado uma quantidade de pontos em uma região muito próxima, fosse exibido um contador. Segue aqui um exemplo - http://www.princiweb.com.br/demos/google-maps-api-v3-criando-mapa-personalizado/

Comment: @AllanRamos Voce tentou seguir os passos desse blog? Percebi que o link dele vai pro MarkerClusterer (sem o Plus), mas que o MarkerClusterer Plus parece ser melhor. Esse é o link do Plus http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.2/

Comment: vi sim e utilizei. Desculpe. Então, eu fiz um teste e inseri 2500 pontos, mas pela proximidade deles, o mapa ficou devagar e não ficaram agrupados corretamente. Olharei agora esse link que você passou. Obrigado !

Comment: @AllanRamos Fiz uns testes e observei que é melhor criar seu array de pontos primeiro, e depois criar o MarkerClusterer, juntando os marcadores de uma vez. Demonstro a alternativa, que é usar `addMarker` uma de cada vez (na funcao ShowResults). Assim, quando arrasto o mapa vejo por uma fraçao de segundo os marcadores. Mesmo assim para 3000 pontos, nao percebi lentidao. Segue o link: http://jsfiddle.net/d49j2gLt/ Pode ser que voce esteja criando uma nova MarkerCluster para cada ponto, isso sim pode causar lentidao. Só precisamos de um objeto MarkerCluster e usar addMarker se for necessario.